# Is there a way of creating a "natural" highlighter effect through Kdenlive?

Tags: effects, kdenlive, visual-effects

On [15:20 of *How To Make Vox Style Videos - After Effects Tutorial*](https://youtu.be/F7A503llNBA?t=920), YouTuber Mapal uses *Turbulent Displace* in After Effects to add a more natural look to the highlighter/marker effect typical of Vox videos. Note how the edges are imperfect, so they appear more natural:

[image: Note the edges on the highlighter effect]

Is there a way of doing something like that through Kdenlive?

The rest of the highlighter effect is shown in both these 2 videos:

- [Simple4Brain Tech Tutorials - *Correct way✅ to highlight text in #kdenlive  23.08.1 (without changing opacity) | Simple4Brain*](https://youtu.be/p-J2x_6bnZM)
- [Fabiano from Brazil - *KDENLIVE: Marker effect | Text highlighter effect in 2 minutes*](https://youtu.be/mtiyl9qCnJw)

> I've also asked [this question on r/kdenlive](https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/17szys6/is_there_a_way_of_creating_a_natural_highlighter/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: [@Arkengheist suggested the effect pixs0r on r/kdenlive](https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/17szys6/comment/k8togtt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).